# how do i get this python function to return a value?

Tags: python

I have a file which I'm reading in python(test.txt). Sample file contents are as follows.

```
cool let's/cool
hi let's/hi
somek let's/somek
```

I'm searching for cool and if it exists in this file i'm trying to fetch the value let's/cool

I have tried this

```
file = open('test.txt')
my_value='cool'

def test_function(my_value):
    for line in file:
        #fields = line.strip().split()
        if line.find(my_value) != -1:
            ddda=line.rsplit(" ",1)[1]

            print(ddda)  ###This is giving my value let's/cool

while true:
    b=test_function(my_value)
    print(b) ##not able to fetch the value of ddda here
```

How do I store the value of ddda in my while loop.
Is there a better way of doing things without using function?
I'm not using any external modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(ddda)  ###This is giving my value let's/cool
```

This is not giving you anything. It is *printing*. If you want to *return* a value, then `return` it, not `print` it.

```
return ddda
```

Doing this will allow you to `print(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, return that value:

```
print(ddda)
return ddda
```